Why does std::atomic.wait() hang when used in shared memory?
I have this simple program:
// shared_memory.hpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

struct SharedMemory {
  char message[100];
  std::atomic<std::uint32_t> last_update_nanotime;
};

// sender.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include "shared_memory.hpp"
#include <thread>

int main() {
  std::string filename = "/tmp/boost_shared_memory";
  boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file mfile(
      boost::interprocess::open_or_create, filename.c_str(), 1000);
  auto* shared_mem = mfile.find_or_construct<SharedMemory>("SharedMemory")();

  while(true) {
    std::cout << "Locking & writing" << std::endl;
    {
      uint64_t nanotime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
          std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
      shared_mem->last_update_nanotime = nanotime;
      shared_mem->last_update_nanotime.notify_all();
    }
    std::cout << "Set time " << shared_mem->last_update_nanotime << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

// receiver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/sharable_lock.hpp>
#include "shared_memory.hpp"
#include <thread>

int main() {
  std::string filename = "/tmp/boost_shared_memory";
  boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file mfile(
      boost::interprocess::open_or_create, filename.c_str(), 1000);

  auto* shared_mem = mfile.find_or_construct<SharedMemory>("SharedMemory")();
  uint64_t last_update_nanotime = shared_mem->last_update_nanotime;

  std::cout << "is lock free? " << shared_mem->last_update_nanotime.is_lock_free() << std::endl;

  while(true) {
    std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
    {
      shared_mem->last_update_nanotime.wait(last_update_nanotime);
      last_update_nanotime = shared_mem->last_update_nanotime;
      std::cout << "Received: " << shared_mem->message << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

Why does receiver.cpp hang at shared_mem->last_update_nanotime.wait(last_update_nanotime)?
Doing a busy-wait on the value of shared_mem->last_update_nanotime instead of using wait() works fine.
I'm using g++ 13.1.0 and -std=gnu++23 although this should be supported in C++20 as well.

shared memory doesn't exist in C++ Standard, atomics are intended to be thread-safe nothing more. Although there is a note in the Standard that seem to indicate the lock-free atomics should be also address-free, but I'm not sure if that is applicable to your case: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics.lockfree#4

@Gene It does specifically say "This restriction enables communication by memory that is...shared between two processes" which seems like it should apply here.

if that clause applies to your case then I suggest you check is_lock_free() (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/atomics.lockfree)

What operating system is this?

@NateEldredge Linux, kernel 5.15

@Gene is_lock_free() is true

C++ does not have interprocess synchronization primitives.  Shared memory is for sharing data. You can't just put c++ classes into (shared) memory. There will be no clear owner (which process is going to own the lifecycle and call the constructor for example?).
So keep shared memory for data (trivially constructible/trivially destructible/trivially copyable) types only. And find an OS specific interprocess signal that you can use to synchronize

@PepijnKramer In this case, the first process that reaches boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file::find_or_construct will call the constructor, as the name implies. I would love to find an OS specific interprocess signal, but POSIX does not provide a robust condition variable, so if one of the processes crashes the condition variable is left in an invalid state and notify_all() hangs. This is what brought me to std::atomic as a possible workaround. It's not clear why constructing it in shared memory should be a problem, particularly since it's explicitly called out in the standard.

Your code doesn't compile: ‘struct SharedMemory’ has no member named ‘message’

Also, in the code you posted, the sender never calls notify.  Please check that the code you posted actually matches the version you are testing.

That said, I have a conjecture.  What happens if you change the atomic variable from uint64_t to uint32_t?

I believe that atomic wait/notify under Linux uses the futex kernel API, which only directly supports 32-bit objects.  So when you use C++20 wait/notify on an object of a different size, the library creates an auxiliary 32-bit word elsewhere in memory (e.g. malloced) to use as the futex, with a table that maps the address of the atomic object to its futex.

For a variable shared between threads, this works fine because all threads see it at the same address, and the futex can be placed anywhere in memory and will be shared by all threads.  But for memory shared between processes, this won't work, because the malloc'ed memory where the futex is created will not be shared.  So I suspect the two processes end up working with two separate futexes that won't see each other's notifications.

Later versions of Linux (apparently 5.16 and onward) provide a futex2 call which allows you to request a futex of a different size (8/16/32/64 bits).  Using that, your code in principle could work.  However, there may be some question whether the kernel actually supports additional sizes, and I also don't know whether libstdc++ uses futex2 when available.

@NateEldredge Apologies, I have updated the code so it should match and compile now. I tried uint64_t to uint32_t but unfortunately it does not seem to make a difference

Hm.  Well, either way, I think the answer is simply going to be "this is not supported and nobody ever claimed that it was".  The comment in the C++ standard about being address-free is merely a "should"; it would be up to each individual implementation to specify if this is actually the case.  In effect, on Linux, atomics up to 64 bits (and maybe 128) are address-free for purposes of load/store/RMW, but not for purposes of wait/notify.

@NateEldredge Your explanation about the futex at a different address makes sense, thanks for your help

My comment was mainly about standard C++, so I missed that boost does some things for you here. I am also not so familiar with linux (I usually have to deal withstandard C++ only both Windows/Linux). This seems interesting though : posix interprocess semaphore, and this semaphores on linux

@NateEldredge: Weird.  Last I checked, libstdc++'s atomic wait / notify_one uses futex without FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG IIRC, so it would work across processes if used directly on the shared memory.  vs. std::mutex using PRIVATE futex ops that only work within one process.  If it doesn't actually work across processes, it might as well use FUTEX_PRIVATE_FLAG .

Hmm, actually, when I try it under strace on Ubuntu 24.04 x86-64, the receiver calls FUTEX_WAIT without private, so that's good, but the sender doesn't seem to make any futex call at all.  So maybe I don't actually understand how this works.  Perhaps it notices that the program has only one thread and therefore there is nobody to notify?  I'll explore further if I have a chance.

Hmm I would expect the private flag from https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_wait.h#L113 if I understood that.

FWIW, this implies there is a waiter count optimize the notification path (no notify if no waiters): https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/12/06/implementing-c20-atomic-waiting-libstdc#making_notify_cheaper
